# Fetching from db and showing it to the android table

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL table and show it to the Android table.

For table design I am using the following dependencies.

```
de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0
```

My JsonArray

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "sl": "36",
            "user_id": "575512",
            "email": "m@gmail.com",
            "password": "123",
            "name": "Moderator",
            "gender": "Male",
            "phone": "1223345",
            "lvl": "Moderator",
            "stat": "1"
        },
        {
            "sl": "68",
            "user_id": "814769",
            "email": "m2@gmail.com",
            "password": "1WCcvnhp",
            "name": "Test Moderator",
            "gender": "Male",
            "phone": "7412589630",
            "lvl": "Moderator",
            "stat": "1"
        },
        {
            "sl": "69",
            "user_id": "742136",
            "email": "m3@gmail.com",
            "password": "YG5*3Kj9",
            "name": "Mod3",
            "gender": "Male",
            "phone": "1423687450",
            "lvl": "Moderator",
            "stat": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Till now my code:

```
JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

    modUpdateAdapter.setName(name);
    modUpdateAdapter.setPhone(phone);
    modUpdateAdapter.setEmail(email);
    arrayList.add(modUpdateAdapter);
}

showData();
```

And the `showData` function is

```
public void showData(){
    data = new String[arrayList.size()][10];

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
        modUpdateAdapter = arrayList.get(j);
        data[j][0] = modUpdateAdapter.getName();
        data[j][1] = modUpdateAdapter.getEmail();
        data[j][2] = modUpdateAdapter.getPhone();
    }

    tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), data));
}
```

Problem is that only the last value is shown 3 times, even if I call the `showData()` inside the for loop. I want to show all 3 objects from the array, not a single object 3 times. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem while you are parsing the data from the JSON and putting the data into an `ArrayList` of `modUpdateAdapter`. You are not creating a new instance of `ModUpdateAdapter` each time you are setting the name, email and phone. So each time you are parsing a data and saving it in the same `modUpdateAdapter` class. So the function needs to modified like the following.

```
JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String phone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

    // Each time create a new instance and then save the value.
    ModUpdateAdapter modUpdateAdapter = new ModUpdateAdapter();

    modUpdateAdapter.setName(name);
    modUpdateAdapter.setPhone(phone);
    modUpdateAdapter.setEmail(email);
    arrayList.add(modUpdateAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just saved my evening.